# Hover Activated Accordion + Smooth transitioning between states

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the accordion style [here:](https://anacuna.com/en/) I am having trouble with:

I would appreciate telling me what the functions are called that I want to implement. :)

1. Getting the text hidden partially to finally show when hovered over
2. Filling with a colour on hover
3. Having the accordions move like folder tabs, i.e. move up when hovered over and back down again when hovered down.

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
/* The Magic */
.accordion:hover .accordion-item:hover .accordion-item-content,
.accordion .accordion-item--default .accordion-item-content {
    height: 2em;
}

.accordion-item-content,
.accordion:hover .accordion-item-content {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .25s;
}

/* Aesthetic */
body {
  background: #222;
}

.accordion {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "PT Sans" sans-serif
}

.accordion .accordion-item {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #eee, #f5f5f5, #eee);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #eee;
}

.accordion h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion .accordion-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: hsl(200, 80%, 60%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, hsl(200, 80%, 60%), hsl(200, 80%, 45%) 2em, hsl(200, 80%, 60%));

}

.accordion .accordion-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: hsl(280, 60%, 45%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, hsl(280, 80%, 60%), hsl(280, 60%, 45%) 2em, hsl(280, 80%, 60%));
}

.accordion .accordion-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: hsl(40, 80%, 40%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, hsl(40, 80%, 60%), hsl(40, 80%, 45%) 2em, hsl(40, 80%, 60%));
}

.accordion .accordion-item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: hsl(80, 40%, 40%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, hsl(80, 80%, 40%), hsl(80, 80%, 35%) 2em, hsl(80, 80%, 40%));
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <section class="accordion-item">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
          <p font-size="20px">Content for section 1</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="accordion-item">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
          <p>Content for section 2</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section  class="accordion-item">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
          <p>Content for section 3</p>
          <p>This is my default state.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="accordion-item">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
          <p>Content for section 4</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the basics you need. Happy coding.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.red:hover{background-color: red;}
.blue:hover{background-color: blue;}
.green:hover{background-color: green;}
.purple:hover{background-color: purple;}

.menu {padding: 0px;}

.menu-item {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  
  transition: background-color 0.2s, transform 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(0px); /* Also used for to preserve correct z-index for description */
}

.menu-item:hover {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  color: white;
}

.menu-item-title {font-size: 30px; font-weight: 700;}
.menu-item-text{font-size: 12px; opacity: 0.8; font-weight: 600; padding-top: 20px;}

footer { margin-top: 40px;  border-top: 1px solid black; position: relative; z-index: 100; padding: 20px; background-color: white;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div class="menu-item red">
   <div class="menu-item-title">Section 1</div>
   <div class="menu-item-text">Description 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item blue">
   <div class="menu-item-title">Section 2</div>
   <div class="menu-item-text">Description 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item green">
   <div class="menu-item-title">Section 3</div>
   <div class="menu-item-text">Description 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item purple">
   <div class="menu-item-title">Section 4</div>
   <div class="menu-item-text">Description 4</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<footer>This is end of page</footer>
```